# Android custom authentication with gestures

Tags: android, authentication, gesture

I am working on an application that will have a **custom solution for user identification** inside the android app. This will be a secure application, and there are some interactions where the user must give a specific code before the server give the green light for the action (for example: car engine start; open the door after NFC tag readed; stop or start the ship's engine, turn on/off computer)

So, we need a custom authentication/authorization. But **typing PIN code** (or other passwords) are not user friendly, and it is slow. So we want to implement this functionality with **recorded key gestures**, like the default screen lock gesture in android. There will be an image (or some layout) with 3x3 (or 4x4) fleck, and with fingers we must detect a gesture to identify the user.

The question is simple, what is the best way, or best pattern to implement this functionality? I was searching for solutions for similar problems, but not found any easy way.

Thanks for the answers.

**EDIT:**

I have not found any useable solution or example, so i must implement a widget for this feature. But I need some help again. The plan is, i use 3x3 buttons and i will save the order of the touched buttons like a PIN code. This is the sketch:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Bae6_nM0_b8/U1jFa_Fd7XI/AAAAAAAAWvk/wRmvgXQwZSE/w484-h516-no/stackoverfloww-android-gesture.png

The design plan:

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-vJdqynm6edI/U1jN1C8p8RI/AAAAAAAAWwY/Yw9UIQq2Xuk/w503-h837-no/stackoverfloww-android-gesture-2.png

But there is no event for "**onhover**" as in html. There are some events (onTouch and brothers), but they are not good for this problem. So, the question is, the best solution is recording **MotionEvent**-s with **gesture listener**, get the button positions, and calculate the hitted (hovered) buttons?

Comment: If you really need this to be secure, using touch gestures is not a good idea as the resulting smears can be easily lifted from the device. And with your example I don't really see the difference between entering a pin and touching buttons in a specific order.

Comment: These buttons will be not clicked, only hovered when the user make the gesture.

Comment: Ohh, I my question is toughy, so I think the best way is to implement a custom control with key gestures. I was so naive, for the first sight it seemed easier.